# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> GoogleTagManagerService]: Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, google-tag-manager

i have also imported HttpClientModule and also properly configure GoogleTagManagerService.

```js
import { HttpClientModule, /* other http imports */ } from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   HttpClientModule,
  ]}),
  providers: [
    { provide: 'googleTagManagerId', useValue: 'GTM-XXXXXXX' }
  ],
});
```

But i am still getting errors .
i am using Google Tag Manager package and import every things properly .
and now i clone the project in new system, so now i am getting this error

**app.component.ts code**

```js
import { GoogleTagManagerService } from 'angular-google-tag-manager';

constructor(
  private gtmService: GoogleTagManagerService
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
    if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      const gtmTag = {
        event: 'page',
        pageName: evt.url
      };
      this.gtmService.pushTag(gtmTag);
    }
    if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
      return;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: Can you show us more code / errors that you are getting?

Comment: ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> GoogleTagManagerService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> GoogleTagManagerService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for GoogleTagManagerService!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4201/vendor.js:53072:27)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4201/vendor.js:53399:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4201/vendor.js:53325:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4201/vendor.js:53188:20)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4201/vendor.js:53399:24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in an resolved issue from this package, you have to use an older version of this package for angular 8 (https://github.com/mzuccaroli/angular-google-tag-manager/issues/38)

`npm i --save angular-google-tag-manager@1.1.4`

Answer (score 0):

It seems everything is ok. You can restart your app with `ng run`.

I advise you to follow the steps on that blog:

https://itnext.io/how-to-add-google-tag-manager-to-an-angular-application-fc68624386e2

Or, you can cross-check your app with the demo-page.

https://github.com/mzuccaroli/angular-google-tag-manager/tree/master/demo-application

And, last but not least, you can re-install the package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-google-tag-manager